# Tabview with datatable paging issue

Tags: view, tabs, datatable

i have an Issue link to tab view
it contains 4 tabs: every tabs contains 1 or 2 datatable.
i have a problem usually with the first tab.
when I go the the page number 2 in the datatable in the first tab
then I cant edit or delete the row.
but it woks good in the first page
and i works good in the others tabs in all pages

I try to switch the table but usually same pb with the 1st tab.
Can some one help me please . good bless you